# How do i run a for loop in bash one after another

Tags: linux, bash

I have about 100 files in a folder but I would like the for loop in bash to run one after the other and not all at once. This is my script on the command line: 
`for i in *.fasta; some program here & done`

This runs the script in the background and does all 100 files at once which crashes my server because it is memory intensive. I would like it to run one after the other automatically.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in *.fasta; do some program here; done
```

or if you want to run the whole loop in the background

```
for i in *.fasta; do some program here ; done &
```